# Метка [обработка-данных]: синонимизировать или сжечь?

Tags: предложение, метки, синонимы-меток, удаление-метки

Нашел тут на сайте такую метку: [обработка-данных](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85). Мне кажется, что ее стоит поставить в очередь на сжигание, по той причине, что она слишком общая. Ее можно влепить практически на любой вопрос, касающийся данных — хоть по Excel, хоть по валидации e-mail, хоть по django или sql.

Правда, есть у нас метка [наука-о-данных](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%83%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%be-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85) (всего с одним вопросом). Можно синонимизировать с ней, хотя я не знаю, будет ли это выходом из положения.

Comment: Надо удалить. Но кто этим будет заниматься? У нас на повестке [куча таких меток](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/64517908#64517908).

Comment: Что-то много тут уже комментариев стало. Пожалуйста, не пишите здесь ничего, лучше пишите [в автоматически сгенерированном чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149127/discussion-between--and-).

Comment: Есть еще похожий [анализ-данных], ее надо немного почистить, оставить только реально подходящие под нее вопросы. Это уже другая тема, правда.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Согласен, что обработка данных - это слишком общее понятие, так как под это практически подпадает все программирование. Есть сомнения, что метку нужно так сразу удалять. Там много вопросов по статистическому анализу данных (по поиску закономерностей в больших массивах данных), это уже более узкая тема. На таких вопросах, скорее всего, нужно поменять метку на [анализ-данных](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85) или что-то подобное.

Смущает также, что у метки есть описание, и его добавил не какой-то ламер/копипастер, а активный отвечающий именно по тематике анализа данных. Хотелось бы услышать мнение специалистов в этой области перед тем, как удалять метку. Лучше пока подождать с массовыми правками.

Comment: Хорошо, подожду. Переключаюсь пока на яндекс. Ответ временно не принимаю, жду мнения специалистов)

Comment: так это калька с [\[data-processing\]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/data-processing/info), вероятно